# Append filters to sql results on a collection in laravel

Tags: php, sql, laravel

So with pure PHP and MySQL i can get away with filtering an query for example. $sql = select*from users; then i have the drop downs, country province and districts.

if a user selects nothing, click get report all users are displayed. If user select any from drop eg. country it should then narrow down the result based on country selected. user can also implement the same on all dropdowns.

So i am trying to archive the same with Laravel i will show you my code.

Already i have selected and joined tables and its bringing back my results. i have tried to add a where to the results if a dropdwon value is set but its then not giving me results like i expect

```
$results = DB::table('people')
            ->leftJoin('contacts', 'people.id', '=', 'contacts.person_id')
            ->leftJoin('provinces', 'contacts.province_id', '=', 'provinces.id')
            ->leftJoin('nationalities', 'people.nationality_id', '=', 'nationalities.id')
            ->leftJoin('districts', 'contacts.district_id', '=', 'districts.id')
            ->select('people.*', 'contacts.*', 'provinces.name AS province_name',
                'nationalities.name AS nationality', 'districts.name AS district_name');

        if (request()->has('nationality_id')) {
            $nationality_id = request('nationality_id');
            $results->where('people.nationality', '=', $nationality_id)->get();
        }

        return view('reports.index', compact('results', 'nationalities', 'provinces'));
```

i expect that if i select dropdown and like province it filters the collection with the selected value of province being selected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should edit this code:

```
 if (request()->has('nationality_id')) {
            $nationality_id = request('nationality_id');
            $results =   $results->where('people.nationality', '=', $nationality_id)->get();
        }
```

To be this:

```
if ($nationality_id = request('nationality_id')) {
        $results = $results->where('people.nationality', '=', $nationality_id);
    }

$results = $results->get()
```

Answer (score 0):

try this maybe it helps you

```
if (request()->has('nationality_id')) {
   $nationality_id = request('nationality_id');
   $results = DB::table('people')
        ->leftJoin('contacts', 'people.id', '=', 'contacts.person_id')
        ->leftJoin('provinces', 'contacts.province_id', '=', 'provinces.id')
        ->leftJoin('nationalities', 'people.nationality_id', '=', 'nationalities.id')
        ->leftJoin('districts', 'contacts.district_id', '=', 'districts.id')
        ->select('people.*', 'contacts.*', 'provinces.name AS province_name',
            'nationalities.name AS nationality', 'districts.name AS district_name')
        ->where('people.nationality', '=', $nationality_id)->get();
}else{
  $results = DB::table('people')
        ->leftJoin('contacts', 'people.id', '=', 'contacts.person_id')
        ->leftJoin('provinces', 'contacts.province_id', '=', 'provinces.id')
        ->leftJoin('nationalities', 'people.nationality_id', '=', 'nationalities.id')
        ->leftJoin('districts', 'contacts.district_id', '=', 'districts.id')
        ->select('people.*', 'contacts.*', 'provinces.name AS province_name',
            'nationalities.name AS nationality', 'districts.name AS district_name')
        ->get();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should rewrite `$results` variable:

```
//...
if (request()->has('nationality_id')) {
    $nationality_id = request('nationality_id');
    $results = $results->where('people.nationality', '=', $nationality_id)->get();
}
//...
```

Comment: i would to have three drop downs where one can either select nationality alone or nationality and province together, or just province alone but still filter the results

Comment: you should build your request depending to the user input. Add new `where` condition every time when you detect some value from your drop downs. If did everything correct for nationality, just add another conditions for another drop downs, but do not forget to rewrite `$results`

Answer (score 0):

Problem is with this line

```
$results->where('people.nationality', '=', $nationality_id)->get();
```

->get() method is returnin new `Collection` object, which you need to pass to another variable.

`$results` itslef is a `Builder`instance.

Just change

```
 $results->where('people.nationality', '=', $nationality_id)->get();
```

To

```
 $results = $results->where('people.nationality', '=', $nationality_id)->get();
```

And you will get what you want.